# windows 10 Lock Screen: asking for username and password

Tags: windows, windows-10

My lock screen always ask me for username and password, my coworkers computer only ask for password? how can i change it to only ask me for password?

Comment: Why the Downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phoebeli's answers guided me to the correct answer.
*Interactive logon: Do not display last user name* was enabled in the Domain, the default is "disabled"

When we disable this policy, i no longer have the issue.

I did not have this issue when i was on Win8.1, which is weird why when im on Win10 all of teh sudden that policy took effect.

Answer (score 6):

Open Local Security Policy by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, typing secpol.msc into the search box, and then clicking secpol.‌

In the left pane, expand Local Policies, and click local policies on Security Options. (See screenshot below)
[image]

(See screenshot below)

[image]

You can select the option you want, and click on OK.

Lock the computer (Windows Key + L) to see the change.

Comment: thank you for the great help!

Answer (score 1):

If a policy is set on the computer (or domain) "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name : ENABLED" then you might need to do more, as per [this forum posting](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1104135-windows-10-requiring-username-and-password-for-lock-screen):

1) Click start-> run -> gpedit.msc 
2) Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> "Interactive Logon: Display user information when the session is locked" to "User display name, domain and user names"
3) Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon -> Hide Entry points for Fast User Switching to "Enabled"